# Is there a better way to apply isnull to all columns than what I'm doing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

A number of times over the last month I've had to replace 'null' fields with '0' to every column returned from a query.

to save a lot of time (some of these are returning a high number of columns) I've been using the following and then pasting the results for relevant columns into a new query:

```
select      ',  isnull(' + COLUMN_NAME + ', 0)' + ' as ' + COLUMN_NAME
from        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where       TABLE_NAME = 'summary_by_scca_sales_category '
            and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'property''
```

Essentially I'm wondering if there's a better way that I can do this? Ideally a method where I could automatically apply isnull to all columns being returned in a query (without using two queries).

For example:

I want to take a query like:

```
select  *
from    tablename
```

And for every column returned by * replace null results with 0 without having to write an isnull() line for each column.

**edit**:

Will accomplish this with a view (doh, should have thought of that). For interests / educations sake is there a way to do something like this with code also?

Comment: If `null` _should_ actually be `0` in the data, can you just update the tables to replace `null` with `0` and make the columns not-null with a default of `0`?  Then you wouldn't have to check for it on every `SELECT`.

Comment: I'd love to and have pushed for it but unfortunately I'm not in a position to do that nor have I been able to make it happen :( The dba's have pushed back saying that the regression testing involved for various other systems using the db makes it too difficult to do.

Comment: That would only make sense for numeric field types. Why not create a view that you produce with your script? then you can do select * from view_tablename if you want the null handled result.

Comment: Ah, a classic battle of pushing responsibilities between teams.  In that case I imagine the `VIEW` answer below is probably your best bet.  It might need to be updated with schema changes, unless you wrap it in more `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` magic.  Depends on the needs of the `SELECT`s I guess.

Comment: Yup, going to do that - should have thought of it originally but still learning. Still wondering if the original question is possible with code though (for educations / curiosities sake)

Comment: @David that was my first thought as well...

Comment: however annoying, null serves a purpose... and should not be replaced with "0" unless that is in fact the value it was intended.  i think it might be easier to write a view to convert it to 0 when you need it to be 0.

Comment: @samyi Your comment is quite redundant as this is entirely dependant on the data / database. Why say something for the sake of saying something? Would much rather a positive contribution.

Comment: @Michael Sorry didn't read all the comments. No need to be rude.

Comment: @samyi Very true, tough morning - sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a `VIEW` against the tables in question where the `ISNULL` logic you want is set up.  Then queries against the views would return the data you want.

EDIT:

As requested, some sample code to accomplish creating the `VIEW`s automatically.  This is pretty gross, but for something that only has to be run once it will work.  Beware of type issues (you stated everything should transmute to 0 so I assume all your columns are of a suitable numeric type):

```
DECLARE @table_def varchar(max)
SET @table_def = 'CREATE VIEW <tname>_NoNull AS SELECT '

SELECT @table_def = REPLACE(@table_def, '<tname>', t.name) + 
    'ISNULL(' + c.name + ', 0) AS ' + c.name + ', '
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = <<table name>>

SELECT @table_def
```

Comment: Very good point, not sure why I didn't consider that. For interest / educations sake is there a way to do this (this being my original question) with code also?

Comment: There is -- you can use very similar logic to what you have above, and just dynamically create and execute `CREATE VIEW` statements.

Comment: @Codingo: Probably not a _good_ way, if there is.  A `VIEW` is semantically and intuitively the closest thing you're looking for... A view of the table with some special considerations.

Comment: To be honest I'm not too sure how to do that (only been using SQL a couple of months) - Could you provide an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the table and column names in the QUOTENAME function when you're generating @table_def so that things like [Product Name] don't break it.